# $().ready after being called by ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, document-ready

This code works perfect. But after I call it with ajax it doesn't run.
 I'm pretty sure that the problem resides in $().ready but I haven't figured out what to replace it with.
Any ideas?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function () {

var mensagem = "<?= $mensagem ?>";
var id= "<?= $linha ?>";

var nextMsgOptions = {
    msg:  mensagem,
    side: "bottomMiddle",       
    CSSClass: "nextMsg-LightTheme",}

$(id).click(function(){
    $(id).nextMsg(nextMsgOptions);
});


});
</script>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on what exactly it is you are trying to do? The `$().ready` event is the equivalent of the `window.onload` event so it will execute after the page has loaded. I don't see why you would need to programmatically call this?

Comment: I'd agree with @James, you should move the contents of your `ready` function to a different function, and just call it from the `ready`. This way you can call it at a different point as well and not have to go via the `$().ready`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, but does your script come within ajax request? If yes, you need to use jQuery live on your click function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function () {

var mensagem = "<?= $mensagem ?>";
var id= "<?= $linha ?>";

var nextMsgOptions = {
    msg:  mensagem,
    side: "bottomMiddle",       
    CSSClass: "nextMsg-LightTheme",}

$(id).live('click',function(){
    $(id).nextMsg(nextMsgOptions);
});


});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   var mensagem = "<?= $mensagem ?>";
   var id= "<?= $linha ?>";

   var nextMsgOptions = {
      msg:  mensagem,
      side: "bottomMiddle",       
      CSSClass: "nextMsg-LightTheme",}

   $(id).click(function(){
      $(id).nextMsg(nextMsgOptions);
   });

});
```

Comment: Could also be written as `$(function() {...})` or `$.ready(function() {...})`

Comment: The OP's syntax is valid, ugly but still valid.